# How to sync scripts in SuiteCloud?

Tags: netsuite, suitecloud

I'm unable to sync scripts from my NetSuite account.
When I try to login into project account as admin I get TWO_FA_REQD error and when I try sync scripts I get SoapException without any stacktrace.

I believe I must first login and then sync.

This is my complete workflow:

- I've created new suite cloud project
- set SuiteScript as project type
- set dummy name
- set master password
- login into project account (got TWO_FA_REQD)
- sync scripts id from account (got SoapException)

I use SuiteCloud IDE 2019.1.1 Build Date: 11 Apr 2019 16:43:44

Should I enable something in NetSuite first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mandatory 2FA Now Enforced for Integration Access to NetSuite**

NetSuite began enforcing the mandatory two-factor authentication (2FA) requirement in all NetSuite accounts as of 2018.2. By default, the Administrator and other highly privileged roles are designated as 2FA required, and this requirement cannot be removed. Any standard or customized roles subject to the 2FA requirement are indicated in the Mandatory 2FA column on the Two-Factor Authentication Roles page.

### [image]

**Integrations that employ user credentials to access NetSuite may be subject to mandatory 2FA in the following situations:**

- NLAuth for RESTlets. For more information, see the help topic Using User Credentials for RESTlet Authentication.
- SuiteTalk (web services) integrations that use the login operation. For more information, see the help topic login.
- SuiteTalk (web services) integrations that use the passport element sent as Request Level Credentials (RLC). For more information, see the help topic Request-Level Credentials.
- Inbound SSO integrations that use the mapSso operation. For more information, see the help topic mapSso.

---

Your integrations must use certain functions that require a highly privileged
role. You should transition these integrations to use token-based authentication (TBA) rather than user credentials, or specify a less-privileged role that does not require 2FA. For more information, see the help topic Token-based Authentication (TBA). For information about using TBA with your integrations, see the help topic Integration Management.

Setting Up Token-based Authentication Roles
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/82075

OAuth Library Consumption for Client Application
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42171

Comment: I'm unable to activate TBA on Netsuite 2019.2 UI. When I navigate to "Enable features" page I only see three buttons save, cancel and reset. There are no tabs or checkboxes where I can check which feature I wanna enable. Should I enable something someware before I can get access to TBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you have TBA enabled, you're using tokens, and you still get `TWO_FA_REQD`, it may be because SuiteCloud Development Framework is not enabled in your account.

Oddly, NetSuite has an integration pre-made for the IDE called "SuiteCloud Development Integration" even with SuiteCloud Development Framework disabled. You can even create Administrator access tokens with it. But when you use them in the IDE, you get TWO_FA_REQD.